# Generate signed apk android studio - Error with key

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

I am trying to generate signed apk with an exiting keystore 
but i have following problem

```
Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read key MedicalAssistanceKey from store "D:\MedicalAsError:com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key MedicalAssistanceKey from store

 "D:\MedicalAss_download\MyKey.jks": Cannot recover keys_download\MyKey.jks": Cannot recover key

Error:java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

I am sure the password and  key are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keystore and key passwords have to be the same.
You could use commands to modify passwork as below:

```
keytool -storepasswd -new [insert new keystore password] -keystore [insert keystore file name]

keytool -keypasswd -alias [insert alias] -new [insert new key password] -keystore [insert keystore file name]
```

Or if you like GUI, download from http://keystore-explorer.org/

Note: keytool.exe exists in jdk/bin folder or jre/bin folder.

Comment: i don't understand what to do please explain more in details

Comment: run given commands to reset passwords, and make two passwords same.

Answer (score 0):

if you have special characters in your passwords use this tool to change it:

http://keystore-explorer.org/

special characters like `Ç`

[image]